# Is there a way to open an iPhone app when there's an incoming call?

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to open an iPhone app when there's an incoming call?

Comment: Don't worry, Apple took already care of it and iOS will open the telephone app for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the time of writing (iOS 4.3), this isn't currently possible.

Additionally, I personally find it very unlikely that Apple would enable this in future releases, as it would potentially interfere with the "actually using it as a phone" related aspects of the iPhone. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The user can open an app of his or her choosing during a call, but there's no way to have your app launch when a call arrives using public API.